# Can you embed an image in a watson conversation chatbot responses?

Tags: chatbot, watson

I can insert hyperlinks and they work fine. I have seen bots with images. Is this not possible with Watson conversation?

Answer (score 2):

Watson Conversation does not allow the storage of images.  It does allow you to pass back context/information to your client application that can then render the image.

Answer (score -1):

You can send a url at response JSON editor from watson interface:

```
{
"output":
 {
    "attachment": {
      "type": "image",
      "payload": {
        "url": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1061/1924/products/Sad_Face_Emoji_large.png?v=1480481055"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

It is possible, add the image to your project folder and reference it on the Watson conversation service for e.g add it in the img folder then on Watson conversation add

```
<img src='..img/pic.jpg'>
```